# Angularjs ng-if not working but logging boolean shows expected value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I have a directive that has some basic logic that hides and shows text items on the page.  This logic works correct half of the time but doesn't work the other half of the time.  The code I have in my directive is:

```
newco.directive 'heroHeadline', ($routeParams, $interpolate, $rootScope, paramsStateService) ->
  restrict: 'E'
  templateUrl: '/pages/shared/hero_headline'
  scope:
    marquee: "="
  link: (scope, el, attrs) ->
    scope.displayInternationalCopy = false
    scope.displayHeadline2 = false
    if paramsStateService.customerCategoryId is 'international'
       scope.displayInternationalCopy = true
    else
      classification = $routeParams.classification
      classification ?= 'us'
      doubleHeadlineClassifications = ["latino", "us"]
      scope.displayHeadline2 = if classification in doubleHeadlineClassifications then true

    console.log(scope.displayInternationalCopy)
```

The template I have is:

```
p.uppercase(ng-if="!displayInternationalCopy")
  | Dishworld is now Sling International
  h1.invert
    span.copy The #1 International
    span.copy TV Service in the U.S.
  p Sign up today for as low as $25/mo. (and sometimes lower!)
h1#marquee-headline-1.invert ng-if="displayInternationalCopy"
  interpolate(value="{{ marquee.headline1 | heroHeadline | perMonth }}" params="basePack")
h2#marquee-headline-2 ng-hide="displayHeadline2 "
  interpolate(value="{{ marquee.headline2 | heroHeadline | perMonth }}" params="basePack")
  | {{displayHeadline2}}
```

The console.log of displayInternationalCopy is showing as false but the top part of the template is still rendering.  For the other case(when displayInternationalCopy evaluates to true) shows correctly.  I have used this pattern in several places on the app with no issues and I am just perplexed at this point.

Also the view that the directive is being shown in is:

```
section.jumbotron#international style="background-color: #000" ng-class="{lefty: isDomestic, white: !isDomestic }"
  img#hero.hidden-xs height='616'  src="{{ marquee.heroImage }}"

  .p ng-class="{hero_gradient: !isDomestic}"
  .transbox.visible-xs
  .copy-international
    .container-fluid
      .container
        hero-headline(marquee="marquee")
        a.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg#watch_now(role="button" rel="nofollow" ng-click="signUp($event); toggleHBO(false); " user-flow="")
          | {{ classification.cta_button }}
        hero-attribution
```

Comment: It should be `scope.$parent.displayInternationalCopy` inside directive..because directive is using isolated scope..or pass `displayInternationalCopy` in isolated scope using attribute

Comment: It is a scoping issue for sure.  I wish I could mark you as the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Check I've added an answer

Answer (score 0):

You're using isolated scope inside your directive, which is creating new scope which is not prototypically inherited from its parent. That says that you can not access parent scope directly inside you directive. You need to either use `$parent.` to refer parent `scope` like `scope.$parent.displayInternationalCopy` **OR** you need to include `displayInternationalCopy` variable inside the isolated scope like `displayInternationalCopy: '='` so that the `displayInternationalCopy` scope variable of parent will be available inside your directive scope.